# Intersection of parametric surfaces

Tags: 3d, surface, 3d-model

I want to get the curve of intersection of two surfaces. The best way of representing this curve for further use would be a function with the parameter t. But my problem is a bit deeper, because I do not know the best way to represent parametric surfaces.
I could not find much information about this topic on the internet. (I only got articles about how to solve for the curve of intersection by hand. You only have to solve a set of equations.) I am currently developing
a IOS App (Swift).

The two questions?
What is the best way to represent a parametric surfaces?
How to intersect two parametric surfaces?

I am looking for the intersection curve on the surfaces (So the intersection is only a 2d curve). It would be nice if someone could point me out some links to useful websites.

Answer (score 0):

Developing a solid model library that can compute arbitrary intersections is probably not something that you want to do from scratch.

Instead, look for libraries that you can use or license. A well known free one is from [OpenCascade](https://dev.opencascade.org/doc/overview/html/occt_samples_ios_uikit.html).

The Wikipedia page on [Geometric Modeling Kernels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_modeling_kernel) might be a good jumping off point for research.

Comment: I will have a look into it, but I would really like to write it my self. Maybe I find a perfect kernel.

Comment: Here's an open textbook that you might find useful: https://web.mit.edu/hyperbook/Patrikalakis-Maekawa-Cho/mathe.html.  Section 5 gets into intersection problems.